# Ubuntu connection refused database connection

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I'm having a problem connecting the 2 machine I can ping my database but when I try to connect it using **MYSQL** is says connection refused.

[image]

Comment: You're not really "pinging your database". You can ping your machine which is not an indication that you can connect to the database. You need to check that the mysql server is running on the machine you want to connect to and that the correct port is open. You might want to look at, for example, [How to set up MySQL for remote access on Ubuntu Server 16.04](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-up-mysql-for-remote-access-on-ubuntu-server-16-04/).

Answer (score 0):

It cloud be due to two reasons :

1. There is a firewall block from the network your server is in.
2. And for connecting using IP address of host-name you should do it through remote desktop connection. First connect to the remote desktop connection using the IP address and open your SQL tool. if you have the accessibility to server locally, then you should use appropriate connection string name on your SQL client with port name which will vary.